# Some questions about coding ActiveX Script/VBScript in SQL Server Agent Jobs/DTS packages

Tags: email, vbscript

I use SQL Server Agent Jobs/DTS packages, coded in ActiveX Script/VBScript.
It works fine.

But there are some issues I would need help at the moment:

- First: Is there a possibility to send an html email out of the ActiveX Script code in the DTS Step?

My company doesn't want to buy a separate commercial DLL for sending smtp email .. like JMail for example.
I know there are many such DLLs I could buy which can be used to send an email using VB or other languages.
But we don't have the money for such external components.

Could I use SQL Server Database Mail?
... but it is necessary to send the mails in html ...

- Is there a possibility to create a new *.txt, *.csv or *.xlsx file from the ActiveX Script/VBScript code in the DTS Step?

I would like to copy the html email body code (a string which I built in the ActiveX Script code) into these files and attach them to the email I send out of the script code. So the user/recipient gets the html content embedded in the email body and separate in files too.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Tommy

Answer (score 0):

This code works. **PLUS** it displays any errors which tell you why it didn't work.

```
Set emailObj      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
emailObj.From     = "dc@gmail.com"

emailObj.To       = "dc@gmail.com"

emailObj.Subject  = "Test CDO"
emailObj.TextBody = "Test CDO"

emailObj.AddAttachment "C:/Users/User/Desktop/err.fff"

Set emailConfig = emailObj.Configuration

emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")    = 2  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl")      = true 
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")    = "dc"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")    = "Ss"
emailConfig.Fields.Update

On Error Resume Next
emailObj.Send

If err.number = 0 then 
 Msgbox "Done"
Else
 Msgbox err.number & " " & err.description
 err.clear
End If
```

Also your account at www.gmail.com needs to be set to allow SMTP access (if using gmail as many are who do this).

The configuration info comes from Outlook Express (last in WinXP, renamed to Windows Mail in Vista, and dropped from Win7 and later). This shows default configuration on your computer. You may need to install Windows Live Mail. You also have to turn on the SMTP service in Windows Features.

```
Set emailConfig = emailObj.Configuration
On Error Resume Next    
For Each fld in emailConfig.Fields
    Text = Text & vbcrlf & fld.name & " = " & fld
    If err.number <> 0 then
        Text = Text & vbcrlf & fld.name & " = Error - probably trying to read password - not allowed"
        err.clear
    End If
Next
Msgbox Replace(Text, "http://schemas.microsoft.com", "")
```

Also CDO for Windows 2000 is not always included in all editions/versions of windows. See http://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/171440.

### .

Comment: Many thanks. That's a good way. Searched for the whole CDO documentation. It's fine.

Tommy